# The multithreaded asynchronous HTTP-server from the asio documentation doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, server, boost-asio

I am trying to write my own asynchronous multithreaded server using boost asio. Firstly I decided to look into the official documentation and try some examples from it. When I run the first example I saw that it doesn't utilize my cores as I expected and the total "requests per second" value was small.

I've tried different testing applications.

1. Apache JMeter. 
   Test data was: 10 000 users and 1-sec Ramp-Up Period.
   The results:

```
C:\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin>jmeter -n -t "Thread Group.jmx" -l testresults.jtl
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using Thread Group.jmx
Starting the test @ Sun Jun 09 02:43:23 EEST 2019 (1560037403700)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
summary +   2926 in 00:00:06 =  502.5/s Avg:  1318 Min:     1 Max:  4677 Err:    20 (0.68%) Active: 1778 Started: 2102 Finished: 324
summary +  27074 in 00:00:21 = 1284.1/s Avg:   804 Min:     0 Max:  4607 Err:  3183 (11.76%) Active: 0 Started: 10000 Finished: 10000
summary =  30000 in 00:00:27 = 1114.9/s Avg:   854 Min:     0 Max:  4677 Err:  3203 (10.68%)
Tidying up ...    @ Sun Jun 09 02:43:51 EEST 2019 (1560037431085)
... end of run
```

2. Apache Benchmark.
   Test data was: 10 000 user and 10 000 requests (1 request per user).
   The results:

```
sudo ab -n 10000 -c 10000 http://localhost:80/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1807734 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 1000 requests
Completed 2000 requests
Completed 3000 requests
Completed 4000 requests
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 6000 requests
Completed 7000 requests
Completed 8000 requests
Completed 9000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Finished 10000 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        141 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10000
Time taken for tests:   19.530 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      2050000 bytes
HTML transferred:       1410000 bytes
Requests per second:    512.02 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       19530.384 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.953 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          102.50 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:     1273 11835 4933.3  12964   17732
Processing:   529  965 243.3    972    1387
Waiting:      115  697 331.8    697    1272
Total:       1802 12800 5172.5  13936   19119

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  13936
  66%  16538
  75%  17553
  80%  18045
  90%  18708
  95%  18922
  98%  19008
  99%  19048
 100%  19119 (longest request)
```

3. Intel Vtune Amplifier.
   I've also run these tests under the VTune to test the core utilization. In both cases, it gives from 5 to 10 percents.

The code is available here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/server3/

And if you want to download the entire project with configured CMake - check this repository: https://github.com/YevheniiM/HttpServerBoostAsio

So, I expected the results to be around 10-15k requests per second, based on the previous experience of my colleagues. And the core utilization also should be greater (I have the laptop with Core i5, 2 physical cores, 4 in hyperthreading and the server was run on 4 threads).
The most surprising here is that I didn't change anything - the actual code from the documentation somehow works wrong (or probably my tests are incorrect).

I would much appreciate any ideas of what am I doing wrong!

Comment: Did you set  `num_threads` parameter while running the server?

Comment: Of course I did